# How do I print a multi-dimensional array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, printing, multidimensional-array

What's the preferred method of printing a multi-dimensional array in ruby?

For example, suppose I have this 2D array:

```
x = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I try to print it:

```
>> print x
123456
```

Also what doesn't work:

```
>> puts x
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant as a grid. Never mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're just looking for debugging output that is easy to read, "p" is useful (it calls inspect() on the array)

```
p x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Either:

```
p x
```

-or-

```
require 'pp'

. . .        

pp x
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning 'pp', which I didn't even know existed.  It seems to do the same thing as inspect for this example on ruby 1.9.2 though.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to take your multi-dimensional array and present it as a visual representation of a two dimensional graph, this works nicely:

```
x.each do |r|
  puts r.each { |p| p }.join(" ")
end
```

Then you end with something like this in your terminal:

```
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

Comment: what's the use of `.map { |p| p }` ?!

Comment: thanks for the note. you could do each instead of map. I will edit the sample to use each since it's more appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

[PrettyPrint](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pp/rdoc/index.html), which comes with Ruby, will do this for you:

```
require 'pp'
x = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
pp x
```

However the output in Ruby 1.9.2 (which you should try to use, if possible) does this automatically:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > x = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > p x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each entry in the "enclosing" array. Each entry in that array is another array, so iterate over that as well. Print. Or, use `join`.

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

arr.each do |inner|
  inner.each do |n|
    print n # Or "#{n} " if you want spaces.
  end
  puts
end

arr.each do |inner|
  puts inner.join(" ") # Or empty string if you don't want spaces.
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'fundamental' way to do this, and the way that IRB does it, is to print the output of `#inspect`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > x = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > x.inspect
 => "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]"
```

`pp` produces slightly nicer output, however.