# Output an Array of objects to terminal, as a table with attributes in fixed-width columns

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting, string-conversion

I am attempting to output a 2D array to the console; I want the information in the array to be nicely formatted as shown in my desired output at the end of this question. My array is created as follows (instances are created of the `FamilyMember` class):

```
#family_members.rb

class FamilyMember

attr_accessor :name, :sex, :status, :age
def initialize (name, sex, type, role, age)
   @name = name
   @sex = sex
   @type = type
   @role = role
   @age = age
end

end

# Below, an array is created called fm; instances of the class are then instantiated within the array elements
fm = {}
fm[1] = FamilyMember.new('Andrew','Male', 'Child', 'Son' , '27' )
fm[2] = FamilyMember.new('Bill','Male', 'Parent', 'Father' , '63' )
fm[3] = FamilyMember.new('Samantha','Female', 'Parent', 'Mother' , '62' )
fm[4] = FamilyMember.new('Thomas','Male', 'Child', 'Dog' , '10' )
fm[5] = FamilyMember.new('Samantha', 'Female', 'Child', 'Dog' , '4' )
```

I want to be able to output the contents of the array to the console formatted as a string. I need to be able to do this two ways - using `each` and seperately by using `do`.

What I have attempted ([inspired by a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478300/how-do-i-print-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-ruby)):

```
def eacharray(an_array)
  an_array.each do |inner|
      puts inner.join(" ")
  end
end

eacharray(fm)
```

However the output from the above is as follows:

```
1 #<FamilyMember:0x000000027e7d48>
2 #<FamilyMember:0x000000027e7c58>
3 #<FamilyMember:0x000000027e7b68>
4 #<FamilyMember:0x000000027e7a78>
5 #<FamilyMember:0x000000027e7988>
```

How do I output the 2D array elements nicely formatted using `each` and `do`?. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Ideally, my output would be like this:

```
Family Member   Name     Sex     Type    Role    Age
1               Andrew   Male    Child   Son     27
2               Bill     Male    Parent  Father  63
3               Samantha Female  Parent  Mother  62 
4               Thomas   Male    Child   Dog     10
5               Samantha Female  Child   Dog     4
```

Comment: what is your expected output.. example please.. I didn't get this *I want to be able to output the contents of the array to the console formatted as a string*.

Comment: Your `fn` is not an array, it is a hash.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I have added my preferred output to my Question. thanks

Comment: @Jenny then you need to code for that.. Did you do? :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit  .. no I did not do it, I need code :)

Comment: How is this a 2D array? A family member is not an array.

Comment: @Linuxios what is it then? A hash? Thanks, I am new to programming - I will read about hash

Comment: @Jenny: the family members are objects. I suggest you do some reading on Object Oriented Programming principles.

Comment: @Linuxios is `fm` not an array of `objects`? I am working with and reading about OOP every day.

Comment: @Jenny: You initialise `fm` to a hash with `{}` and assign to five different elements of it. For an array you want `fm = []`, and then you should probably push onto it using `fm << FamilyMember.new(...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're happy with a fixed format (you could build the format dynamically depending on the maximum data width in each field) you could write something like this.

```
class FamilyMember
  attr_accessor :name, :sex, :type, :role, :age
  def initialize (*args)
    @name, @sex, @type, @role, @age = args
  end
end

fm = []
fm << FamilyMember.new( 'Andrew',   'Male',   'Child',  'Son' ,    '27' )
fm << FamilyMember.new( 'Bill',     'Male',   'Parent', 'Father',  '63' )
fm << FamilyMember.new( 'Samantha', 'Female', 'Parent', 'Mother',  '62' )
fm << FamilyMember.new( 'Thomas',    'Male',  'Child',  'Dog' ,    '10' )
fm << FamilyMember.new( 'Samantha', 'Female', 'Child',  'Dog' ,     '4' )

format = '%-15s %-8s %-7s %-7s %-7s %s'
puts format % ['Family Member', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Type', 'Role', 'Age']
fm.each_with_index do |member, i|
  puts format % [ i+1, member.name, member.sex, member.type, member.role, member.age ]
end
```

**output**

```
Family Member   Name     Sex     Type    Role    Age
1               Andrew   Male    Child   Son     27
2               Bill     Male    Parent  Father  63
3               Samantha Female  Parent  Mother  62
4               Thomas   Male    Child   Dog     10
5               Samantha Female  Child   Dog     4
```

You can also use `for ... in`, which actually compiles to pretty much the same loop, using the `each` iterator.

```
i = 0
for member in fm do
  i += 1
  puts format % [ i, member.name, member.sex, member.type, member.role, member.age ]
end
```

or you can use the primitive `while` or `until` loop constructs, which most Ruby programmers forget about. Ruby is much more expressive using its iterators.

```
i = 0
while member = fm[i] do
  i += 1
  puts format % [ i, member.name, member.sex, member.type, member.role, member.age ]
end
```

**Note** that you can omit the `do` from both of these last examples. As long as you have a newline (or a semicolon) after the `while` expression Ruby will understand just fine.

Comment: Thanks Borodin; this works great. Is there a way to do it without using a `do` in the array search? I am attempting to do this too (requirement for university assignment) By saying `%-15s` etc you are specifying the width of the column?

Comment: @Jenny: I'm not sure what you mean Jenny. `do` ... `end` are brackets that enclose the list of statements to do for `each` array element. You could use braces instead: `{` ... `}` is similar. The `%` operator on a string uses the left-hand operand as a format for [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), and a format specifier like `%-15s` means a left-justified (`-`) fifteen-character (`15`) string field (`s`).

Comment: @Jenny: Ah, if this is for an assignment then I think I understand. I've added to my answer to explain. (Are you supposed to be asking Stack Overflow for answers?)

Comment: Thanks @Borodin..I will examine your additions tomorrow. .as for assignment stuff -as long as I understand the stuff I don't see the problem(the original code is all mine anyway). We have to fully explain our answer's anyway. .like a "ruby for dummies" book might do.

Answer (score 1):

A class like your FamilyMember is most easily constructed with a Struct. The result is just a class, but with some extra features.

```
FamilyMember = Struct.new(:name, :sex, :type, :status, :age)
fm = []
fm << FamilyMember.new('Andrew','Male', 'Child', 'Son' , '27' )
fm << FamilyMember.new('Bill','Male', 'Parent', 'Father' , '63' )

puts FamilyMember.members.map(&:capitalize).join("\t") #members gives you the names of all methods
fm.each{|fam_member|puts fam_member.values.join("\t")} #another feature.
```

Output:

```
 Name   Sex Type    Status  Age
 Andrew Male    Child   Son 27
 Bill   Male    Parent  Father  63
```

Only lined out...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that, This may be not relevant now. But Just sharing this so someone can take advantage.

Try This Gem - terminal-table

[terminal-table](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table)